SQL Error [900] [42000]: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
I'm working on a Oracle stored procedure , my oracle database version is Oracle Database 11.2.0.1.0 , I'm very familiar with MySQL and SQL Server as well but I am really new to Oracle, I tried to program a stored procedure it's not working
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_ybm_for_exp_yb_ybjs IS

  CURSOR cur_exp_yb_ybjs IS
    SELECT setl_id, PHARMACY_ID, PATIENT_ID, prodno, batchno, created
    FROM exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy;

  v_setl_id      exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy.setl_id%TYPE;
  v_PHARMACY_ID   exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy.PHARMACY_ID%TYPE;
  v_PATIENT_ID   exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy.PATIENT_ID%TYPE;
  v_prodno       exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy.prodno%TYPE;
  v_batchno       exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy.batchno%TYPE;
  v_created    exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy.created%TYPE;

  myYBFL_ML yw_spxxhzb.YBFL_ML%TYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur_exp_yb_ybjs;

  LOOP
    FETCH cur_exp_yb_ybjs INTO v_setl_id, v_PHARMACY_ID, v_PATIENT_ID, v_prodno, v_batchno, v_created;
    EXIT WHEN cur_exp_yb_ybjs%NOTFOUND;

    BEGIN
      -- Check if the record exists in yw_spxxhzb
      SELECT YBFL_ML
      INTO myYBFL_ML
      FROM (
       SELECT YBFL_ML, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created DESC) AS rn
        FROM yw_spxxhzb
        WHERE created <= v_created AND prodno = v_prodno
      )
      WHERE rn = 1;

      -- Update the target table
      UPDATE exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy
      SET ITEM_ID= myYBFL_ML
      WHERE setl_id = v_setl_id
        AND PHARMACY_ID = v_PHARMACY_ID
        AND PATIENT_ID = v_PATIENT_ID
        AND prodno = v_prodno
        AND batchno = v_batchno
        AND created = v_created;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        
        -- Handle case where no matching record is found
        NULL; -- No action needed if no record is found
    END;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur_exp_yb_ybjs;
END update_ybm_for_exp_yb_ybjs;
/

the problem I encountered was
   SQL Error [900] [42000]: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
   Error position: line: 8

the code of line was
   v_setl_id      exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy.setl_id%TYPE

any idea what mistakes I made in this stored procedure ? any suggestions ? thank you so much
I hope this stored procedure was created successfully

Assuming the tables and columns are right, the procedure should compile; and it shouldn't be able to get that error anyway. Which client are you running this in? Some don't understand PL/SQL properly, or scripts - are there other statements before this? Alternatively, are you sure the error is from creating the procedure, and not from calling it after it's been created? What does the user_errors view show?

@AlexPoole thank you for your help, the error was encountered when it was trying to be created , I try to retrieve the user_errors view, the result shows that stored procedure was invalid sadly

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; and the expected output for your sample data.

@MT0  thank you for your helps , my table was based on a select statement, it's really complex but fortunately finally my records were stored in it correctly, sorry im afraid it's the complex struct is presence.

Cursor loops are slow; you want to do it all in SQL if possible.
You appear to be modifying the current row of the table to set the ITEM_ID to the latest YBFL_ML (that does not exceed the created date of the destination table). You can do that using a MERGE statement and correlating on the ROWID pseudo-column and a correlated sub-query to find the latest ID:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_ybm_for_exp_yb_ybjs
IS
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy dst
  USING (
    SELECT ROWID AS rid,
           (
             SELECT MAX(YBFL_ML) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY created)
             FROM   yw_spxxhzb y
             WHERE  y.created <= e.created AND y.prodno = e.prodno
           ) AS YBFL_ML
    FROM   exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy e
  ) src
  ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET ITEM_ID = src.YBFL_ML;
END update_ybm_for_exp_yb_ybjs;
/

Which, for the sample data (ignoring all the columns that become irrelevant if you correlate on ROWID):
CREATE TABLE exp_yb_ybjs_20240604_copy (prodno, created, item_id) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '1980-01-01', -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '1990-01-01', -1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE yw_spxxhzb (prodno, created, ybfl_ml) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '1971-01-01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '1972-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '1979-01-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '1980-01-01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '1981-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '1970-01-01', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '1980-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '1990-01-01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2000-01-01', 1 FROM DUAL;

Then, after running the procedure, the table contains:



PRODNO
CREATED
ITEM_ID




1
1970-01-01 00:00:00
1


2
1980-01-01 00:00:00
2


3
1990-01-01 00:00:00
2



fiddle
